# C#, Use of Unsigned Local Variable

Tags: c#, permissions, gpo

The GPPermissionCollection Class has no Constructor and i don't know how to declare object of it or use it.

```
GPDomain domain = new GPDomain(sDCName + "." + sDCExtention);
Gpo gpo_background = domain.CreateGpo("August-HCalendarGPO");

GPPermission gp = new GPPermission("Everyone", GPPermissionType.GpoEditDeleteModifySecurity, false) ;
GPPermissionCollection gppc;
gppc.Add(gp);  //This Line Has Error
gpo_background.SetSecurityInfo(gppc);
```

the "gppc.Add(gp);" has error " Use of Unsigned Local Variable" .
how to fix this error ?
any help will appeciated

Comment: The error is fairly self explanatory, have you tried anything to fix it?

Comment: `GPPermissionCollection gppc;` you've just declared it not created a new instance or anything. missing the `= new GPPermissionCollection()` ?

Comment: @DavidG the GPPermissionCollection Has no constructor.i dont know how can i Initialize GPPermissionCollection object.

Comment: @matt the class has no constructor

Comment: So what do you expect the `SetSecurityInfo` when you pass it an uninitialised object?

Comment: "has no constructor".... it surely has one, but you may not be allowed to access it. It's probably `internal`, MS often does this to special collections. If you read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.grouppolicy.gppermissioncollection(v=vs.85).aspx), you will see that even your `gppc.Add()` call won't do what you expect.

Comment: @DavidG then how can i initialize this guy?

Comment: I have no idea, I know nothing about these classes. Perhaps try reading the docs or finding example code?

Comment: I think somebody needs to open this question to get answer..

Comment: I don't post it as answer as I don't know the furhter implications: but you can get a working instance of `GPPermissionCollection` by calling `gppc = gpo_background.GetSecurityInfo();`

Comment: @RenéVogt  the SetSecurityInfo Method Takes GPPermissionCollection object, and i cant declare GPPermissionCollection . what should i do know?

Comment: @Matt  the SetSecurityInfo Method Takes GPPermissionCollection object, and i cant declare GPPermissionCollection . what should i do know?

Comment: @DavidG the SetSecurityInfo Method Takes GPPermissionCollection object, and i cant declare GPPermissionCollection . what should i do know?

Comment: @HimBrombeere I disagree with that duplicate. The question is how to get this kind of collection to set new security policies, not about initializing local variables.

Comment: @KhaledRakhisi How about you **read the docs**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of `GPPermissionCollection`, because its constructors are `internal`. You'll need to get that collection from your GPO via [`GetSecurityInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/wmi_v2/class-library/gpo-getsecurityinfo-method-microsoft-grouppolicy):

```
GPDomain domain = new GPDomain(sDCName + "." + sDCExtention);
Gpo gpo_background = domain.CreateGpo("August-HCalendarGPO");

GPPermission gp = new GPPermission("Everyone", GPPermissionType.GpoEditDeleteModifySecurity, false) ;

// get permissions collection from gpo
GPPermissionCollection gppc = gpo_background.GetSecurityInfo();

gppc.Add(gp);
gpo_background.SetSecurityInfo(gppc);
```

Comment: even if this line of code is very simple and easy for you but it helped me a lot .thank you very much.